# Get payment method details from confirm setup intent response in Stripe JS

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, expand

Hello everyone and good night :)

I am trying to obtain the payment_method details i.e. card and billing address details from the stripe.confirmSetup call in javascript. I have tried to expand the payment_method parameter with no luck so far. I can retrieve the needed details with a subsequent api call with the newly created payment method but am trying to avoid that if possible.

My code is as follows:

```
    const form = document.getElementById("payment-form"); 
    const stripe = Stripe('pk_test.....s'),
    form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      stripe.confirmSetup({
        clientSecret : "seti_...",
        redirect : "if_required",
        confirmParams : {
          return_url : "example.com/returnURL.php"
        }
      }).then(function(result){
        if(result.error){
          document.getElementById("error-message").textContent = result.error.message;
        }else{
          console.log(result.setupIntent);
        }
    });
```

Thanks for your help! - Midgeypoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to pass an `expand` parameter on a SetupIntent [confirmation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/confirm). When you pass this, you'll get an error `stripe.confirmSetup() parameter: expand is not a recognized parameter.` To get data from the `payment_method`, you can make a separate request to [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/retrieve) the SetupIntent,  on the client side using the [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/object#setup_intent_object-payment_method) parameter. There are a subset of properties that will be returned when using a publishable key with retrieving the Setup Intent which are marked with RETRIEVABLE WITH PUBLISHABLE KEY in the [API document](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/object#setup_intent_object-payment_method) and `payment_method` is one.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought that was probably the case but wanted to check to make sure I wasn't making the extra API call unnecessarily